# Loop through array of html elements and give a specified one a class and the rest another class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This might be a dumb question but I have a function called `selectFace(face);`

and basically what I want the function to do is on the clicked item add a class and then all the other items get another class

what ive got at the moment is

**HTML**

```
<div class="tool_faces">
  <div (click)="selectFace('very-unhappy', 1, $event)" class="tool_faces_circle tool_faces_circle--very-unhappy">
      <img class="very-unhappy" src="../../../../../assets/Images/wellness-faces/very-unhappy.svg" alt="very-unhappy face">
  </div>
  <div (click)="selectFace('unhappy', 2, $event)" class="tool_faces_circle tool_faces_circle--unhappy">
      <img class="unhappy" src="../../../../../assets/Images/wellness-faces/unhappy.svg" alt="unhappy face">
  </div>
  <div (click)="selectFace('okay', 3, $event)" class="tool_faces_circle tool_faces_circle--okay">
      <img class="okay" src="../../../../../assets/Images/wellness-faces/okay.svg" alt="okay face">
  </div>
  <div (click)="selectFace('happy', 4, $event)" class="tool_faces_circle tool_faces_circle--happy">
      <img class="happy" src="../../../../../assets/Images/wellness-faces/happy.svg" alt="happy face">
  </div>
  <div (click)="selectFace('super-happy', 5, $event)"class="tool_faces_circle tool_faces_circle--super-happy">
      <img class="super-happy" src="../../../../../assets/Images/wellness-faces/super-happy.svg" alt="super-happy face">
  </div>
</div>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
selectFace(face, number, event) {
    const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.tool_faces_circle');
    const facesArray = Array.from(nodeList);
    this.selectedFace = number;
    facesArray.forEach(function(item){
      item.classList.remove('tool_select');
      item.classList.add('tool_unselect');
    });
    let getTargetEvent = event.target;
    getTargetEvent.classList.add('tool_select');
}
```

so when you click the div `.tool_faces_circle` it should add a class called `.tool_selected` and for every other face in the `tool_faces` div get a class called `.tool_unselect`

but I cant get it to work.. Im not sure what Im doing wrong..

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: you have selected item set class for it after loop  this.selectedFace = number;

Comment: @nima_moradi sorry I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: in your code ,you seem to find selectedFace  why just not facesArray[number].add('tool_select');

Comment: @nima_moradi I still need to give the class `tool_unselect` to the other ones

Comment: do it after the loop

Comment: @nima_moradi Could you please show me in an answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer

```
selectFace(face, number, event) {
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.tool_faces_circle');
var facesArray = Array.from(nodeList);
this.selectedFace = number;
facesArray.forEach(function(item){
  item.classList.remove('tool_select');
  item.classList.add('tool_unselect');
});

facesArray[number].classList.remove('tool_unselect');
facesArray[number].classList.add('tool_select');

let getTargetEvent = event.target;
//  getTargetEvent.classList.add('tool_select');
}
```

Comment: Hey this worked! my only problem is I can see in the dev tools my classes are being added but.. the styles arent showing up.. any idea what that might be caused by?

Comment: The bottom two parts seem to be doing the same thing, at least partially. You should be able to remove one of them.

Comment: @A61NN5 dumb question, but did you check to make sure the style classes are defined and have the correct selector rule?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel yes just realised my mistake thankyou!